# Playbutton height following Brent Aurelie Flappy Bird tutorial

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Beginner here... I am following Brent's Flappy Bird tutorial, although I am making an Icy Tower like game, but there are things like start screen that are done the same.

The thing is, Brent used an:

```
public static final int WIDTH = 480;
public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
```

in the main java class, and used

```
config.width = CaveEscape.WIDTH;
config.height = CaveEscape.HEIGHT;
```

in the DesktopLauncher class.

That, in turn makes his code for the play button look like this:

```
sb.draw(playbutton, (CaveEscape.WIDTH / 2) - (playbutton.getWidth() / 2), CaveEscape.HEIGHT / 2);
```

And that's fine if you want the play button to be in the center, but I don't. I want it to be up, higher. I can't put it there though since any number higher than 2 is pulling the button downwards, and I can't write any number lower than 2. If I change public final int to double or anything else then my Desktop Launcher code for width and height is giving me errors...

So my question is, how can I change the code to put the play button higher not in the middle of the screen?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

the Answer is, use the table class, put your button in this table then move it wherever you want !

check the [**Table**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) section in the Libgdx wiki to see some exemples.